# Write values to a file in python by adding double quotes to the string with spaces

Tags: python, file, file-format

I am trying to write the values of below list in a txt file , in a specific way

```
valList = ['1','Age',' Address has spaces','employee','98363','hobbies has space in it ']
```

**sample.txt**

```
1,Age,"Address has spaces",employee,98363,"hobbies has space in it "
```

Here if you see valList is a heterogeneous list , my only intention is write the values which had spaces in it surrounded by double quotes, rest all values should be written as it is .
So far I have tried :

```
valList = ['1','Age',' Address has spaces','employee','98363','hobbies has space in it ']
# Output = 1,Age,"Address has spaces",employee,98363,"hobbies has space in it "
valstr = ",".join(valList)
with open('sample.txt','wb') as file:
    file.write(valstr)
    file.write('\n' + " \"" + valList[2] + "\" ")
```

Using  **file.write('\n' + " \"" + valList[2] + "\" ")** line I am able to write a single value with quotes , 
but I need a generic way to write values with spaces in it for the given list .

Any help would be highly appreciated .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have *CSV data*. Use the [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) and it'll automatically use quoting where needed:

```
import csv
valList = ['1', 'Age', ' Address has spaces', 'employee', '98363', 'hobbies has space in it ']
with open('sample.txt', 'wb') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    writer.writerow(valList)
```

This will quote values *as needed*; when there is a comma in the field value, or a newline, for example. This doesn't quite fit your exact requirements but a compliant CSV reader will be able to get the exact same values from the file again when reading.

If you *MUST* have quotes on columns with spaces, you can disable the automatic quoting and add the quotes manually:

```
import csv
valList = ['1','Age',' Address has spaces','employee','98363','hobbies has space in it ']
with open('sample.txt', 'wb') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, quotechar='')
    writer.writerow(['"{}"'.format(v) if ' ' in v else v for v in valList])
```

The list comprehension wraps anything with a space in the value in double quotes. Note that because we disabled quoting here, values with *commas or newlines* in them will be refused by the `csv.writer()` as it now can't quote them.

Demo of both methods:

```
>>> import sys
>>> import csv
>>> valList = ['1', 'Age', ' Address has spaces', 'employee', '98363', 'hobbies has space in it ']
>>> writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout)
>>> writer.writerow(valList)
1,Age, Address has spaces,employee,98363,hobbies has space in it
>>> writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE, quotechar='')
>>> writer.writerow(['"{}"'.format(v) if ' ' in v else v for v in valList])
1,Age," Address has spaces",employee,98363,"hobbies has space in it "
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Martijn , but unfortunately 1st answer will work only if string has a comma in it , and the 2nd solution has a  error '_csv.Error: sequence expected'  . Could you please check once again ,

Comment: @csharpcoder: I updated the second option to use a list comprehension, I forgot the Python 2 CSV writer doesn't like iterators.

Comment: Still I am getting an error in the second solution : _csv.Error: need to escape, but no escapechar set

Comment: @csharpcoder: ah, yes, lets disable the escape character too. Just a sec.

Comment: Thanks 2nd answer worked like charm , But Why Down Votes on my question ?

Comment: @csharpcoder: I don't know why someone voted on your question, I can't read minds, all I can do is give advice. There could be any number of reasons. I find that the better you apply the advice given in [ask], the less likely a question is to received downvotes.

Answer (score 4):

```
valList = ['1','Age',' Address has spaces','employee','98363','hobbies has space in it ']

file = open('sample.txt', 'w')
for item in valList:
    if ' ' in item:
        file.write('"%s",' % item)
    else:
        file.write("%s," % item)
```

Output

```
1,Age," Address has spaces",employee,98363,"hobbies has space in it ",
```